# Mongoose Schema: TypeError: Cannot set property 'generateAuthToken' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I am trying to create a method to userSchema however I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'generateAuthToken' of undefined

```
userSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = function() {
  // const token = jwt.sign({ _id: user._id }, config.get("JWTPRIVATEKEY"));
  const token = jwt.sign({ _id: this._id }, "Privatekey");
  return token;
};
```

**Note: I am not using arrow function instead its a normal function:**

```
var userSchema = {
  name: {
    type: String,
    require: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
    unique: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String
  }
};

userSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = function() {
  // const token = jwt.sign({ _id: user._id }, config.get("JWTPRIVATEKEY"));
  const token = jwt.sign({ _id: this._id }, "Privatekey");
  return token;
};

const User = mongoose.model("Users", new mongoose.Schema(userSchema));

function validateUser(user) {
  let schema = {
    name: Joi.string().required(),
    email: Joi.string()
      .required()
      .email(),
    password: Joi.string().required()
  };

  return Joi.validate(user, schema);
}

exports.User = User;
exports.validateUser = validateUser;
```

**Use case**

```
  let user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });

  const token = user.generateAuthToken();
```

Comment: You're trying to use it as `User.generateAuthToken()` and not `var user = new User(); user.generateAuthToken()` Does that sound like what you are actually doing?

Comment: I believe I am trying to use it as the second example i..e  

  let user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });

  const token = user.generateAuthToken();

Comment: question updated, read the last bit

Comment: So where in your actual code are you checking that `user` was not returned as `null`. If there is no matching email, then that's what happens. The implementation ( which is all you are actually showing us ) only would have been a problem if you actually meant `static`. Since we can now see that is not your intent, it's the "usage" that is now the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `userSchema` just a normal object not a Schema Object. So it doesn't have `methods` property (your `userSchema.methods` is `undefined`) so when you set `userSchema.methods.generateAuthToken`, it will throw an Error.

Please take a look at the document
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods

You should define Schema object first

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    require: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
    unique: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String
  }
});
```

Comment: Nope. Read the docs. [Instance Methods](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods) Nice that you linked to it yourself, but you probably should read it and understand it. Also the schema **is defined first** in the code of the question. So whatever answer this was copied from was also wrong.

Comment: @Neil Lunn well, I already read it and it's the problem I saw. It create new Schema before set methods for instance. Normal object is not mongoose Schema object so it doesn't have `methods`. You can't set property for undefined object

Comment: @Neil Lunn ok, so have you tried it ? If you don't really see the different between mongoose object and normal object just define them and console to see.
Because I already tried it. You just define structure object for the Schema, not a mongoose Schema Object.
Your is `userSchema = {}` and mine is `userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({})`

Comment: Correct! Issue was the schema was a plain javascript object not  a Schema object and therefore didn't have the method property. Another issue was defining the new function after calling the model(). Thanks